# How to create a new column in Pandas DataFrame based on a group of rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have the following data frame:

```
import pandas as pd
cols = 'id,seq,msg'.split(',')

data = [
        ['001',1,'abc aaa'],
        ['001',2,'bcd bbb'],
        ['001',3,'cde ccc'],
        ['001',1,'def ddd'],
        ['001',2,'efg eee'],
        ['001',3,'fgh fff'],
        ['001',4,'ghi ggg'],
        ['002',1,'hij hhh'],
        ['002',2,'ijk iii'],
        ['002',3,'jkl jjj']
]
df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=cols)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
    id  seq      msg
0  001    1  abc aaa
1  001    2  bcd bbb
2  001    3  cde ccc
3  001    1  def ddd
4  001    2  efg eee
5  001    3  fgh fff
6  001    4  ghi ggg
7  002    1  hij hhh
8  002    2  ijk iii
9  002    3  jkl jjj
```

How can I get an output like below:

```
    id  seq      msg msg_num
0  001    1  abc aaa     1
1  001    2  bcd bbb     1
2  001    3  cde ccc     1
3  001    1  def ddd     2
4  001    2  efg eee     2
5  001    3  fgh fff     2
6  001    4  ghi ggg     2
7  002    1  hij hhh     3
8  002    2  ijk iii     3
9  002    3  jkl jjj     3
```

In the above data frame, there are two messages under id# 001 and one message under id# 002. The `seq` field is ordered after the `id` field. Multiple rows of `msg` field creates one message. Whenever a new message starts the seq # changes.

Comment: I'm very confused how we are supposed to understand the logic behind the creation of the `msg_num` column.

Comment: When the `seq` field value changed to 1, it means a new message has started. This is how I got the data, and I need to  assign a number for each message for further processing.

Comment: Thanks everyone for answering the question. Out of several I had to choose one answer. I ran some tests on the data I have. I could not copy paste the tests and results as they were done on a restricted computer. So, I just typed the results here so it becomes useful to the others: On 116,700 rows, both `df['msg_num'] = df.seq.diff().ne(1).cumsum()` and `df['msg_num'] = df.seq.diff().lt(0).cumsum().add(1)` took zero seconds, `df['msg_num']=(df.seq==1).cumsum()` took 0.016 seconds and `df['msg_num'] = df.groupby([e - i for i, e in enumerate(df.seq)], sort=False).ngroup() + 1` took 0.14 seconds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC

```
df.seq.diff().lt(0).cumsum().add(1)
Out[203]: 
0    1
1    1
2    1
3    2
4    2
5    2
6    2
7    3
8    3
9    3
Name: seq, dtype: int64
```

Comment: hah! Mine is just a minor diffirence from yours and a minute late. I delete mine and upvote yours :)  `df.seq.diff().ne(1).cumsum()`

Answer (score 2):

IIUC, you count a new message each time `df.seq` restarts, so you could do:

```
df['msg_num'] = df.groupby([e - i for i, e in enumerate(df.seq)], sort=False).ngroup() + 1
print(df)
```

**Output**

```
    id  seq      msg  msg_num
0  001    1  abc aaa        1
1  001    2  bcd bbb        1
2  001    3  cde ccc        1
3  001    1  def ddd        2
4  001    2  efg eee        2
5  001    3  fgh fff        2
6  001    4  ghi ggg        2
7  002    1  hij hhh        3
8  002    2  ijk iii        3
9  002    3  jkl jjj        3
```

The key idea here is that:

```
[e - i for i, e in enumerate(df.seq)]
```

helps you to identify consecutive ascending runs. As an alternative you could do do:

```
df['msg_num'] = df.groupby(df.seq - df.seq.index, sort=False).ngroup() + 1
```

Comment: Yes, your understanding is correct. I believe, your alternate solution will take less time then the one with for loop to compute when the dataframe will have millions of rows.

Comment: Yes, @Daniel, good idea. I'll test all solutions on the real data. I just have a sample DF running on that does not help.

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
df['msg_num']=(df.seq==1).cumsum()
```

if it not always start with 1:

```
#import numpy as np
df['msg_num']=(df.seq<df.seq.shift(fill_value=np.inf)).cumsum()
print(df)

   id  seq      msg  msg_num
0   1    1  abc aaa        1
1   1    2  bcd bbb        1
2   1    3  cde ccc        1
3   1    1  def ddd        2
4   1    2  efg eee        2
5   1    3  fgh fff        2
6   1    4  ghi ggg        2
7   2    1  hij hhh        3
8   2    2  ijk iii        3
9   2    3  jkl jjj        3
```